# How to use a (copy) command with a (progress bar) script

Tags: bash, shell-script

**Question**

What do I have to type to get this script to work and display a progress bar while it coping a file (`BBC.pdf`). The question is more about running commands with scripts than getting a progress bar to display while coping.

**Progress bar script**

```
#!/bin/sh
cp_p()
{
   strace -q -ewrite cp -- "${1}" "${2}" 2>&1 \
      | awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%3d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent;i++)
                  printf "="
               printf ">"
               for (i=percent;i<100;i++)
                  printf " "
               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=$(stat -c '%s' "${1}") count=0
}
```

**What I have tried**

```
sudo ./cpp.sh /home/user1/Downloads/BBC.pdf /home/user1/

sudo cp ./cpp.sh /home/user1/Downloads/BBC.pdf /home/user1/
```

with *`cpp.sh`* being the script in *`~/scripts`* directory

Comment: maybe i can only add the file info actually in the script its self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script defines a function called `cp_p`, but does not execute it. Remove the function definition and use the code directly.

```
#!/bin/sh
strace -q -ewrite cp -- "${1}" "${2}" 2>&1 \
  | awk …
```

If you want to keep the function definition, run it at the end. This isn't useful here, but can be useful in a larger script with multiple functions.

```
#!/bin/sh
cp_p()
{
    …
}
cp_p "$@"
```

Either way, to run the script, you just run

```
./cpp.sh /home/user1/Downloads/BBC.pdf /home/user1/
```

assuming that the file `cpp.sh` is in the current directory.

Note that in your post, there's a space before `#!` on the first line. If that's a copy-paste error, please fix your question. If the space is in your script, remove it: `#!` must be the first two bytes of the script.

Comment: I think my script is just wrong as a get no progress bar and the files doesn't copy but i understand how to run the script with the command so thanks very much for your help.